# how to scale deep learning on multiple GPUs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, distributed-computing

Need some help in scaling training process to multiple GPUs

```
"learning_rate": 1.0e-3,
"normalization": null,
"validation": 0.20,
"epochs": 64,
"batch_size": 8192,
"num_layers": 128,
"neurons": 256,
"dropout": 0.45,
"optimizer": "adam",
"momentum": 0.0,
"withmomentum": false,
"skip": 2,
"inter_activation": "leakyrelu",
"regularization": null,
"batch_normalization": false,
"scale": false,
"scale_block_repeat": 1,
"indim": 15,
"outdim": 13
```

I am currently trying to parallelize RNN neural network training. I have scaled my model from 1 to 2GPUs, 2 to 4GPUs. I saw increase in training speeds. I used tensorflow distributed. For all the time I was getting around 55% accuracy for 1024 epoch steps.

However when I increased GPUs from 4 to 8, I did not see any speed up. so I doubled my batch size. Now I am getting faster training speed in 8GPUs but accuracy is very low around 7%. Can you suggest me what I can tune ?